# What does FSR stand for in mountain bikes?

Tags: mountain-bike, terminology

What does FSR stand for in mountain bikes?

Ref: http://www.bergwerk.ch/archives/3726/specialized-enduro-comp-2013/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FSR is the name of a suspension design from Specialized. According to a [FAQ](http://specialized.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/456/~/definition-of-fsr), it originally stood for "Future Shock Rear". The Specialized website contains an [FSR Suspension](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/stories/fsr-suspension) page with marketing information about the system.

Answer (score 3):

As per the Specialized  web site Future-Shock-Rear.

Answer (score 1):

According to [*Mountain Bike Rider*](https://www.mbr.co.uk/news/specialized-stumpjumper-361450#iMBwbmxxU7iFxzdx.99),

> In case you were wondering what the ‘FSR’ acronym means, technically it means ‘Front Suspension and Rear [suspension]’. This is historical acronym that dates back to when suspension forks came out (Stumpjumpers with sus forks were dubbed ‘FS’). When rear suspension came along, they added the ‘R’, hence ‘FSR’.

Comment: Take your pick: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/FSR

Comment: Hmm. I'm kinda suspicious of this, since it contradicts the other two answers, one of which is sourced to Specialized's own website. Unfortunately, that link is now dead and I've not been able to find where it's gone.

Comment: @DavidRicherby FWIW, the weblink is live again and the quote in the answer accurately reflects the article. The accuracy of the _article's_ assertion is another matter (of which I'm also suspicious).

Answer (score -1):

It's a specialized term for their full squish or full suspension mountain bikes originating from the stumpjumper which had fs as a model acronym meaning front suspension as bikes progressed and became full suspension they just added and r so it would incorporate the new rear suspension as well so FSR= FRONT SUSPENSION & REAR

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Please note that this answer has already been given, and in that case it was supported by a reference.  You should only add a new answer if you have something substantive to add that hasn't already been covered.  Please read [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Forest Service Road aka an active or old logging road

Comment: This seems highly unlikely; why would they use an initialism for a US-specific piece of jargon, instead of just saying "trail?"  You might as well guess it stands for "Field Service Representative."  Especially since previous answers have given the actual meaning as sourced from the Specialized website.

Comment: @DavidW Specialized is a US company, so it wouldn't be surprising if they used a US term. Sure, this answer seems to be completely wrong, but that's not the reason.